# SharePoint Online View Formatting: Multiple If Statements Problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I am really struggling with the following if statement inside a group header in SharePoint Online JSON View Formatter:

```
"txtContent": "=if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'A' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != '13', 'something', if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'B' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != '16', 'somethingelse', if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'C' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != '7', 'differentthing'))) ",
```

I have followed several examples, even ones taken from the Microsoft training site, and whilst it works with a single 'if', the minute I stack multiple if statements together, SharePoint seems to just render the whole lot as text... which is really frustrating.

Am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: Can you explore more, maybe design what you want exactly and how you want it to be !

Answer (score 2):

If function has syntax like:

```
if(condition, true_value_statement, false_value_statement)
```

You are missing a `false_value_statement` for last `if` block in your formula.

So, try using this formula with default value set to `''`:

```
"txtContent": "=if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'A' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != 13, 'something', if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'B' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != 16, 'somethingelse', if(@group.fieldData.displayValue == 'C' && Number([$aggregate.value]) != 7, 'differentthing', '')))"
```

**Documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)

Comment: Hi @Alex, does this answer your question?